# Unable to post questions nor able to follow tags, topics or community group in AWS repost

Tags: amazon-web-services, repost

Trying to post questions in AWS repost, but I get following error
`{"err":{"code":"AccessDeniedException","message":"Not authorized"}}`

Same error message when I try to follow (subscribe) to topics, tags or community group.

What am I missing?

Comment: Obviously you must be signed it. Does it work from a different browser on the same machine? Does it work from a different machine? Any chance your session timed out and you simply need to re-authenticate?

Comment: Of course I am signed in. Tried multiple times, even with different browsers. Same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sign in, complete your profile and verify your email before being able to perform any operations on re:Post. You can resend a verification email from the settings page.

Comment: I completed my profile and was signed in but missed verifying email as it went to junk mail. It's good now. Thanks!

Comment: Same Issue. I did verify my email. How many times do I need to verify? Besides, there is no option to resend verification. This is so ridiculous