# Why can't I post a question in AWS re:Post?

Tags: amazon-web-services

This is really driving me crazy.

I have signed in https://repost.aws/questions/ask.

I was able to click "Ask Question" button and edit my question.

But in the end, there is no response when I click the "Post Question" button.

why the button fails?

I checked in the developer mode, and saw this error:

```
Request URL: https://repost.aws/api/v1/content/validateText
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 403 
Remote Address: 13.226.77.78:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Why is AWS stopping a registered customer using their website?????????

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70229175/unable-to-post-questions-nor-able-to-follow-tags-topics-or-community-group-in-a/70291343#70291343

Comment: @OmarRosadio I did verify my email. How many times do I need to verify? Besides, there is no option to resend verification.  This is so ridiculous.